# Просто создаю проект и сразу висит такая ошибка: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, ошибка в этом файле:

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Unity.PlasticSCM.Editor.ProjectDownloader
{
    internal static class ParseArguments
    {
        internal static string CloudProject(Dictionary<string, string> args)
        {
            string data;

            if (!args.TryGetValue(CLOUD_PROJECT, out data))
                return null;

            return data;
        }

        internal static string CloudOrganization(Dictionary<string, string> args)
        {
            string data;

            if (!args.TryGetValue(CLOUD_ORGANIZATION, out data))
                return null;

            return GetOrganizationNameFromData(data);
        }

        internal static string ProjectPath(Dictionary<string, string> args)
        {
            string data;

            if (!args.TryGetValue(CREATE_PROJECT, out data))
                return null;

            return data;
        }

        static string GetOrganizationNameFromData(string data)
        {
            // data is in format: 151d73c7-38cb-4eec-b11e-34764e707226-danipen-unity
            int guidLenght = 36;

            if (data.Length < guidLenght + 1)
                return null;

            return data.Substring(guidLenght + 1);
        }

        const string CLOUD_PROJECT = "-cloudProject";
        const string CLOUD_ORGANIZATION = "-cloudOrganization";
        const string CREATE_PROJECT = "-createProject";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле ошибка немного не банальна и не связана с именем организации (точнее связана, но со сторонней, а не с нашей).
Идём в Windows -> Package Manager, находим там библиотеку Version Control и обновляем её с 2.0.3 до 2.0.4.
И происходит магия, ошибка исчезает. Походу, ребята косячнули с версией библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Итак. Дважды нажми на ошибку(в Unity) и посмотри, на какую строку она ссылается.

> В чëм проблема?

В том, что ты где-то используешь класс, который не назначил в инспекторе

Comment: Я уже изменил вопрос, там не в этом коде ошибка( Там в каком - то системном файле, я его прикрепил

Comment: В 42 строке ошибка говорит

Comment: Такое чувство, будто ты в настройках удалил название организации.

Comment: А где его найти, и где найти эти настройки?

Comment: При билде можешь нажать(снизу) Player Settings (если не путаю), и там можно изменить название компании